# How can I get a model class from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, polymorphism

I have a Model called `Todo.rb` which has an attribute called "`asset`" which is a string.  The string contains the names of Models such as `Call`, `Email`, etc.

They also contain an `asset_id`, which is a specific record of the Asset in ActiveRecord.

How, from a Todo record, can I assign to `asset` from that actual ActiveRecord class?

```
=> #<Todo id: 165, created_at: "2010-11-04 00:49:45", updated_at: "2010-11-04 00:49:45", contact_id: 49, user_id: 1, asset: "Call", asset_id: 2, original_date: "2010-11-18", current_date: "2010-11-18", done_date: nil>
```

From this, I would like `asset` to be the equivalent of:

```
 asset = Call.find(2)
```

I understand conceptually this could be a case of single table inheritance, but I wasn't clear how and I wanted to build it up from the use-case.

Comment: I think I figured it out using constantize...but still playing

Comment: It's not STI (single-table inheritance) - polymorphism is something different.  STI is when multiple models are closely related, and therefore share a table in the database.  STI is rails' only answer for inheritance for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to do here, and there's a much simpler way to do it.  It's called polymorphism.  You want todo's to be able to belong to more than one type of thing - sometimes a call, sometimes email, and so on.  The good news is, you're pretty close already.  Here's how you set it up.

In your migration, rename the "asset" field to "asset_type":

```
rename_column :todos, :asset, :asset_type
```

Now add this to your models:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :asset, :polymorphic => true
end

class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos, :as => :asset
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos, :as => :asset
end
```

In the class that is going to belong_to many different types of objects, you have an asset_type string column, and an asset_id integer column.  And you specify that it belongs to the polymorphic association, as shown above.  Then, in all the models that can have_many todo's, you add the `:as => :asset` part to tell it Rails how to find the associated todo's.

This is very easy, and now it works just like any other has_many.  I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:** This is an article I wrote that illustrates polymorphism not just at the model level, but also throughout your site's forms:

http://kconrails.com/2010/10/19/common-addresses-using-polymorphism-and-nested-attributes-in-rails/

Comment: I've been looking for an explanation of polymorphism -- I did the shortcut with constantize, but I will start to go more in depth into polymorphisms but I always had difficulty understanding, even with the pragmatic programming tutorial....thanks.

Comment: No problem!  I think polymorphism was tough for me to grasp until the first time I actually needed it - like in your case with needing to add todo's to more than one type of thing without having models like call_todo, email_todo, and so on. Your example is a great use case.

Answer (score 2):

Rails has a built-in called constantize which should do the trick:

```
asset = "Call".constantize.find(2)
```

You can also use `Kernel.const_get("Call")` or `eval("Call")` but I would avoid eval if at all possible.

Comment: yep that works --- would score this since am using this and @Sam's -- but gave point to polymoprhism since *someday* I'll migrate to that, but right now just need something working and goingthis way.

Answer (score 2):

```
 asset = todo.asset.capitalize.constantize.find(todo.asset_id)
```

Comment: thanks -- this works...I stumbled upon it as well -- I gave point to polymorphism answer since I *think* ultimately I will have to go there rather than using the send method and figuring it out but this was cleaner for now.